Existence of meromorphic differential form on curve with given multiplicity of zeroes and poles
Let $m \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ be a partition of $2g-2$. Polishuk showed in his paper "Moduli spaces of curves with effective r-spin structures" (arXiv link) that if all entries of $m$ are positive, there always exists a $n$-pointed smooth complex curve of genus $g$ $(C, p_1, \dots, p_n \in \mathcal{M}_{g,n}$) s.t. there exists a section $s \in \Gamma(\Omega_C(-\sum_{k=1}^n m_i p_i))$. He further proved that this question has a smooth Moduli Space of dimension $2g-2+n$.
If one generalizes this question to meromorphic differentials, i.e. considering partitions $m$ with negative entries, it is still known that such a Moduli space is smooth and either empty or of dimension $2g-3+n$. There is an obvious obstruction for the existence of such a pair $(C,s)$ which is the residue condition, from which can conclude that there is not a meromorphic differential form with a single pole, i.e. for a $m$ of the form $(-1, m_2, \dots m_n)$ with all $m_2, \dots, m_n \geq 0$ such a pair $(C, s)$. But is this the only obstruction for the existence of such a pair?
Under which condition on $g$ and $m$ does there exist a $n$-pointed smooth complex curve of genus $g$ $(C, p_1, \dots, p_n \in \mathcal{M}_{g,n}$) s.t. there exists a section $s \in \Gamma(\Omega_C(-\sum_{k=1}^n m_i p_i))$?
